# sockets are exhausted in cpp(RED Linux) server and client open close socket model..?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

i am working for very high Transaction Per Seconds(above 150-300 per instance) servers.
Internally we a have client server(model) is there, Always client connect to server for each request (socket open close model, for each request client will connect to server open a socket and close it). After some time for some  transactions we are getting receive failed error on client side. what am observation is sockets file descriptors more than 1024 then only we got this, for that we increases  server and process level file descriptors configurations (max level 65536), even though we are getting same.

And also we try with select call also, there is no result.If any body having any idea please share it.

Comment: please post the client/server code. Better yet, create and post a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sounds like sockets are not always getting closed if a connection doesn't complete - terminates unexpectedly etc. .

Comment: Also sounds like you need to implement connection-pooling at the client, and multiple request/response cycles per connection at the server.

Comment: hi Galik sir,
socket are closing but some we are observing through netstart -na|grep <MY socket port number> 
All sockets in close wait state (as per system close wait time is 60sec ). After 60 sec those are closed.

Comment: Hi EJP sir,
sir can u share more information on connection-pooling at the client..